# If I put my Photo library on an external drive, can I still see the iCloud version when I disconnect the external drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, photos, external-disk

For my Macbook, I'm considering moving photos to an external storage device. These photos are also on iCloud. If I remove the external storage device, will I still see the iCloud copy of the photos? Does it depend how I have photos configured?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one library connected to iCloud at the same time. This means:

- You can move your iCloud Photo Library to an external disk and it will continue syncing with iCloud
- You can create a new photo library - which won't sync with iCloud by default. If you mark it as your system library, your other one will stop syncing.

If you want to keep a full copy of your iCloud Photo Library on your external disk, while still keeping access on-demand when you don't have the external disk, I recommend this process:

1. Create a new user account and sign into your iCloud account
2. Open Photos on the new account and create a new library on your external disk. Mark it as your system library. You can do this, since it's a separate account. It won't affect your library from your main account.
3. Mark this library to download all photos and allow it to download all your photos.
4. When it completes, you can return to your main account and you have two libraries, both connected to iCloud.

The downside here is of course that the second one will NOT sync unless you login to that second account. I recommend making it a routine to login, open photos, and wait for all data to sync up every few weeks/months.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. This may be implied and supposedly obvious but... so we need the second user account on the mac, both are signed into the same iCloud account. One (the original user account, say) has the icloud library backing store on external storage. With the full resolution setting for full replication. The other, new account, can put the icloud library (the same one...) on internal storage. With optimized storage. In this way, then, by switching accounts it is possible to browse the full library in optimized storage mode, even when the external disk is not attached.

Comment: @StevenLu Each account has its own sync process so yea the one with the optimized storage on-computer library will still sync and be usable